# Read Hashes from Array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, csv, hash

im new to perl (started yesterday evening).
I have a problem with array of hashes.

Following situation:
I have several csv-files from a logging application. The logfiles are created daily and are really bad structured. I want to group them together and show some statistics.
Reading and parsing the csv isn't really a problem, but i want to store the columns inside a hash for easyer access.
Inside the csv-file, the secound column (PhysName) is the column, on which i want to group the data. So i thought, it's a good idea to save only the other columns inside a hash, save several of  these hashes inside an array and save the array inside an other hash, where i take the PhysName as Key.

That wasn't a big deal at all:

```
my %dauerauftraege;

# Glob all CSV-Files in folder
my @files = glob("*.csv");

foreach my $file(@files) {
    # read the file
    open(DATA, "<$file") or die("Could not open File");

    LINE:
    foreach my $line(<DATA>) {
        chomp($line);
        if ($line eq "") {
            next LINE;
        }

        # Split Line into Fields
        my @line_data = split(";", $line);

        my $phys_name = $line_data[1];

        # skip the header file
        if ($phys_name eq "PhysName") {
            next LINE;
        }

        my %values =(
        'date_time' => $line_data[0],
        'sender' => $line_data[2],
        'recipient' => $line_data[3],
        'format' => $line_data[4],
        'transport' => $line_data[5],
        'partnername' => $line_data[6]);

        push(\@{$dauerauftraege{"$phys_name"}}, \%values);
    }
}
```

When i try to verify this with `print(Dumper(%dauerauftraege))`i get the following:

```
$VAR1 = 'YYYYYYYXXXXXXXX';
$VAR2 = [
          {
            'transport' => 'FTP',
            'format' => 'V1',
            'partnername' => 'A_TEST',
            'date_time' => '2016.07.25 11:16:52',
            'sender' => 'BBB',
            'recipient' => 'CCC'
          },
          {
            'recipient' => 'CCC',
            'sender' => 'BBB',
            'partnername' => 'A_TEST',
            'date_time' => '2016.07.25 11:17:15',
            'format' => 'V1',
            'transport' => 'FTP'
          }
        ];
$VAR3 = 'XXXXXXXYYYYYYYY';
$VAR4 = [
          {
            'format' => 'V2',
            'partnername' => 'S_TEST',
            'date_time' => '2016.07.25 10:15:02',
            'recipient' => 'DDD',
            'sender' => 'AAA',
            'transport' => 'HTTP'
          },
          {
            'transport' => 'HTTP',
            'recipient' => 'DDD',
            'sender' => 'AAA',
            'partnername' => 'S_TEST',
            'format' => 'V2',
            'date_time' => '2016.07.25 10:15:30'
          }
        ];
```

My first thought was, that Dumper Displays me the odd $VAR's as keys, and the even $VAR's as Values, but after i take a closer look at the hash inside the even $VAR's, i'm pretty shure i have done something wrong while inserting the inner hash (with the columns and values) into the array, stored in the `%dauerauftraege` Hash.

So, now when it comes to read from the Hash, containing an array of hashes with this code here

```
# Get the keys to iterate over them
my @dauerauftraege_keys = keys(%dauerauftraege);
print("count dauerauftraege: ".(scalar @dauerauftraege_keys)."\n");
# iterate over the keys to get the array of hashes
foreach my $dauerauftrag_key (@dauerauftraege_keys) {
    # retrive the array
    my @dauerauftrag = $dauerauftraege{"$dauerauftrag_key"};
    print("count hashes inside the array: ".(scalar @dauerauftrag)."\n");
    # iterate over the hashes and print the values
    foreach my $dauerauftrag_values (@dauerauftrag) {
        print(%{$dauerauftra_values}{'date_time'});
        print("\n");
        print(%{$dauerauftra_values}{'sender'});
        print("\n");
        print(%{$dauerauftra_values}{'recipient'});
        print("\n");
        print(%{$dauerauftra_values}{'format'});
        print("\n");
        print(%{$dauerauftra_values}{'transport'});
        print("\n");
        print(%{$dauerauftra_values}{'partnername'});
        print("\n");
    }
}
```

i always get this error:

```
count dauerauftraege: 2
count hashes inside the array: 1
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./LastRun_Evaluation.pl line 56, <DATA> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./LastRun_Evaluation.pl line 57, <DATA> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./LastRun_Evaluation.pl line 58, <DATA> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./LastRun_Evaluation.pl line 59, <DATA> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./LastRun_Evaluation.pl line 60, <DATA> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./LastRun_Evaluation.pl line 61, <DATA> line 5.
date_timesenderrecipientformattransportpartnernamecount hashes inside the array: 1
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./LastRun_Evaluation.pl line 56, <DATA> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./LastRun_Evaluation.pl line 57, <DATA> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./LastRun_Evaluation.pl line 58, <DATA> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./LastRun_Evaluation.pl line 59, <DATA> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./LastRun_Evaluation.pl line 60, <DATA> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in print at ./LastRun_Evaluation.pl line 61, <DATA> line 5.
date_timesenderrecipientformattransportpartnername
```

That makes me belive, that my problem is in the followinig line:

```
push(\@{$dauerauftraege{"$phys_name"}}, \%values);
```

When i carefully read this line, i understand the following:
`$dauerauftraege{"$phys_name"}` returns me a skalar (`$`) containing an reference to the array, which is dereferenced by `@{}` to  the Array.
And now with `\%values` i pass an reference to the `values` Hash to the `push` Funktion, which add it to the reference to the array, which is indicated by the `\` in front of the @.

I would be verry happy, if anyone could help me with this problem.
Thank you alot guys :-)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8750158b1d3a7f5d840b35c24bd4c16a

Sorry, output too long for this little box here :)
But it looks to me like the same, i've postet above in my question.

Comment: `foreach my $dauerauftrag_values (@dauerauftrag)` and `print(%{$dauerauftra_values}{'date_time'});` name of variable is not identical !!!! `$dauerauftrag_values` NOT A `$dauerauftra_values`

Comment: Always use `use strict;` and `use warnings` ! They help to avoid annoying typos

Comment: I love how everything is in English but the _Daueraufträge_. Those are called _standing orders_ in English. Consistency in variable and function naming is important. It's great that all your vars are snake case, that's the way Perl people typically do it. But you should be consistent with the language that you take the var names from too. That makes it easier to read. Nothing wrong with German, but don't mix. You even have half German half English in there. With a typo in the German word. The longer you wait to fix that the schwieriger it will get. Sounds weird, doesn't it? ;-)

Comment: @simbabque: Yes i know, it's a it weird, in a english code and only one german word. Hopefully my english isn't too bad ;-)

Comment: It amused me. Your English is fine. It's just important to be consistent. Nothing wrong with going all German either. That just makes it hard to get help on it on here. Understanding what variables do is very useful. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is how you access your data structure. Try this:

```
my @dauerauftraege_keys = keys %dauerauftraege;
print("count dauerauftraege: ".(scalar @dauerauftraege_keys)."\n");
# iterate over the keys to get the array of hashes
foreach my $dauerauftrag_key (@dauerauftraege_keys) {
    # retrieve the array
    my $dauerauftrag = $dauerauftraege{"$dauerauftrag_key"}; # ref to array
    my @a = @$dauerauftrag;
    print("count hashes inside the array: ".(scalar @a)."\n");
    # iterate over the hashes and print the values
    foreach my $dauerauftrag_values (@a) { # also a reference
        print $dauerauftrag_values->{'date_time'} . "\n";
        print $dauerauftrag_values->{'sender'} . "\n";
        print $dauerauftrag_values->{'recipient'} . "\n";
        print $dauerauftrag_values->{'format'} . "\n";
        print $dauerauftrag_values->{'transport'} . "\n"; 
        print $dauerauftrag_values->{'partnername'} . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: this really works for me, like a charm. Thank's to your code, i now see, where  i've done the mistake(s). Tank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you don't quite understand how to dereference the data structure. Have a look at the following code which I've changed up a bit in hopes that'll make things a bit clearer:

```
my @keys = keys(%dauerauftraege);

for my $key (@keys) {

    print "*** $key ***\n";

    my $aref = $dauerauftraege{$key};

    for my $values_href (@$aref){
        print "$values_href->{date_time}\n";
        print "$values_href->{sender}\n";
        print "$values_href->{recipient}\n";
        print "$values_href->{format}\n";
        print "$values_href->{transport}\n";
        print "$values_href->{partnername}\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

See [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have some problems with dereferencing.

Answer (score 1):

Always use pragma `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. They help avoid typos and other problems.

`%dauerauftraege` is a hash, you have tried to access it like an array. And you're trying to make a loop through the hash, and at the same time to print on each iteration of the entire hash.

I think the code might look something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %dauerauftraege;

# Glob all CSV-Files in folder
my @files = glob("*.csv");

foreach my $file(@files) {
    # read the file
    open(my $fh, "<", $file) or die("Could not open File");

    LINE:
    foreach my $line(<$fh>) {
        chomp($line);
        next LINE unless($line);

        # Split Line into Fields
        my @line_data = split(";", $line);

        my $phys_name = $line_data[1];

        # skip the header file
        next LINE if ($phys_name eq "PhysName");

        @{$dauerauftraege{"$phys_name"}}
          {'date_time', 'sender', 'recipient',
           'format', 'transport', 'partnername'}=@line_data[0,2..6];
    }
}
```

And print ...

```
# Get the keys to iterate over them
my @dauerauftraege_keys = keys(%dauerauftraege);
print("count dauerauftraege: ".(scalar @dauerauftraege_keys)."\n");
# iterate over the keys to get the array of hashes
foreach my $dauerauftrag_key (@dauerauftraege_keys) {
    print "\n$dauerauftrag_key:\n";
    print join("\n",
          @{$dauerauftraege{"$dauerauftrag_key"}}{'date_time','sender','recipient',
                          'format','transport','partnername'})."\n";
}
```

Comment: Lexical file handles please.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer.
+1 because I like, how you done the "one-line-ifs" with Perl. Like this really much, makes the code looking god :-)
+1 also for the hint of `use strict;` and `use warnings;`! :)